# getting the equation of ellipse using the unit circle.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, solution-verification, conic-sections

Some days ago ,I wondered how to find the equation of ellipse using circle.

so this was my idea.

the equation of a the unit circle with center $(0,0)$ is $x^2+y^2=1$.

So $y=- \sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $y=+ \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

So I considered the difference between a circle and ellipse is that  the ellipse have not a fixed distance between it center and other points.so my idea is starting with unit circle and make the radius not fix.exactly my idea is  compressing or stretching(or both,not with same ratio )the graph of $f(x)=- \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $f(x)=+ \sqrt{1-x^2}$,because that will give me a shape which is  looks like ellipse .

we know that the graph of $g$ with $g(x)=f(\frac{1}{a}x)$ is just the same graph of $f$ but it compressed to the $y$ axis (if $\frac{1}{a}>1$)  or stretched (if $\frac{1}{a}<1$) so if we want to compressing or stretching the graph of $f(x)= \sqrt{1-x^2}$ we can do this instead $f(x)= \sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{a}x)^2}$.(the same for the other sign)

we know that the graph of $g$ with $g(x)=bf(x)$ is just the same graph of $f$ but it compressed to the $x$ axis (if $b>1$)  or stretched (if $b<1$) so if we want to compressing or stretching the graph of $f(x)= \sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{a}x)^2}$ we can do this instead $f(x)= b\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{a}x)^2}$.(the same for the other sign)

wo we will have $y^2=b^2(1-(\frac{1}{a}x)^2)$ with some manipulation we will have this $\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.(now with this steps we can say $2a$ is the Highest width of ellipse and $2b$ is the  Highest height of our ellipse  )

so we will have this equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ wich looks like the exact equation of an ellipse with center $(0,0)$.(if we want the equation of ellipses with other center we can just apply the idea behind $g(x)=f(x+c)$ and $g(x)=f(x)+c$).

so as it seem ,i get the right equation ,but **does the idea and steps is correct** ,because i did not talk about the two  "focus", i did not even considered  the definition of ellipse ,my idea is  just considered  the ellipse as a distorted circle.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If you stretch a circle in one direction, you get an ellipse. And that's exactly how $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1$ relates to $(x/r)^2+(y/r)^2=1$.

Comment: Note, for curves in the plane, it's often an artificial constraint to consider one coordinate a function of the other. In this case, we can get away with just patching together two pieces, but for more complicated curves it can be much worse. (Imagine trying to cut one of [these curves](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rose_(mathematics)#Media/File:Rose-rhodonea-curve-7x9-chart-improved.svg) into pieces, each of which describes $y$ as a function of $x$.)  The strange *inverse* way that we have to deal with the parameters $a$ and $b$ is a consequence of breaking the symmetry between the coordinates.

Comment: okey thanks.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **nice work** deriving the standard equation for the ellipse by stretching the circle independently in each coordinate axis.

---

To answer your question about the foci of the ellipse: there are several definitions of an ellipse, and one can prove that they are all equivalent.

*One* of those definitions is the one you're working with: a circle of radius $1$ whose radius is stretched by independent factors $a$ and $b$ in perpendicular directions yielding the familiar equation
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1. 
$$

*Another* definition is the locus of points $P$ with the property that the sum of the distances $|F_1P| + |F_2P|$ is constant, where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the foci.

Let's assume $a \geq b$, otherwise we have to swap the roles of $x$ and $y$. It turns out that if you place $F_1$ and $F_2$ on the $x$-axis, a distance $c$ from the origin, where
$$
c^2 = a^2 - b^2, 
\tag{1}
$$
and you use $2a$ for total distance, i.e.
$$
|F_1P| + |F_2P| = 2a, 
\tag{2}
$$
then the equation of the ellipse again works out to be
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1. 
$$

---

It's not obvious *a priori* that these two definitions define the same curve in the plane. But, happily, they do! It just takes equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, the Euclidean distance formula, and some algebra to prove it. **Give it a try!**